# While loop is going in an infinite loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a table of member in which fields are `member_id, referrer_member_id, sales_hold_fund`. I want to check if sales hold fund of a member is > 100 and if it is greater than 100 I want to minus the amount 100 from sales hold fund. So this should go in a loop till the sales hold fund is greater than 100.

Example :

> sales hold fund is 300, first it should check if it is greater than
>   100 if yes it will minus 100 from 300, 200 will be the balance amount,
>   again it will check if balance amount is greater than 100, if yes
>   again it will minus 100 from 200. Now it will check if balance amount
>   is greater than 100 not its not greater so it should stop the loop.

I tried to implement this but this is going in an infinite loop.

```
  $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("select Member.sales_hold_fund,Member.referrer_member_id from Member where member_id=?");
    $stmt->execute(array($member_id));
    $memberC = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $fund = $memberC['sales_hold_fund'];

    while($fund > 100)
    {
        $balance_amount = $sales_hold_fund - 100;
        echo $balance_amount;
        $this->updateSalesHoldFund($member_id,$balance_amount);

        $profit_sharing = 0.20 * $amount;

        $referrer_fees = 0.10 * $amount;

        if(!empty($referrer_member_id))
        {
          //  $this->createHundredId($date_of_purchase,$referrer_member_id,$profit_sharing,$referrer_fees,$member_id,$referrer_member_id1);

        }
        else if (!empty($referrer_member_id1))
        {
        //    $this->createHundredId($date_of_purchase,$referrer_member_id,$profit_sharing,$referrer_fees,$member_id,$referrer_member_id1);
        }

        else{
          //  $this->createHundredId($date_of_purchase,$referrer_member_id,$profit_sharing,$referrer_fees,$member_id,$referrer_member_id1);
        }

    }
```

I want to return the balance amount when it is updated and check if it is greater than 100. Now it is going infinite loop because I am only checking if $fund > 100 which is never getting updated.

How can I do this? Please help.. Thank you..

Can anyone help please? Thank you.

Comment: You never do anything with `$fund` inside the loop, so it will always be whatever value it held before entering the loop.

Comment: How can I update the fund and again check it? @Qirel

Comment: you have to perform operation on $fund..

Comment: even you are not using `$fund` anywhere in the code!

Comment: Replace `$sales_hold_fund` and `$balance_amount` with `$fund`

Comment: Set error reporting to `E_ALL`, then you know why your logic doesnt work. A lot of notice errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

You are trying to update the `$sales_hold_fund` and as per your description your code should be as follows. replace your `$fund` with `$sales_hold_fund` and perform operation on it. It will be also replace your `$balance_amount`.

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("select Member.sales_hold_fund,Member.referrer_member_id from Member where member_id=?");
$stmt->execute(array($member_id));
$memberC = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sales_hold_fund = $memberC['sales_hold_fund'];

while($sales_hold_fund > 100)
{
    $sales_hold_fund = $sales_hold_fund - 100;
    echo $sales_hold_fund;
    $this->updateSalesHoldFund($member_id,$sales_hold_fund);

    $profit_sharing = 0.20 * $amount;

    $referrer_fees = 0.10 * $amount;

    if(!empty($referrer_member_id))
    {
      //  $this->createHundredId($date_of_purchase,$referrer_member_id,$profit_sharing,$referrer_fees,$member_id,$referrer_member_id1);

    }
    else if (!empty($referrer_member_id1))
    {
    //    $this->createHundredId($date_of_purchase,$referrer_member_id,$profit_sharing,$referrer_fees,$member_id,$referrer_member_id1);
    }

    else{
      //  $this->createHundredId($date_of_purchase,$referrer_member_id,$profit_sharing,$referrer_fees,$member_id,$referrer_member_id1);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Sid I have updated my answer. It might be helpful for you.

Comment: yes but I need to save balance amount in another variable then add it to fund.. like this  while($fund > 100)
        {
            $balance_fund = $fund - 100;
            $fund = $balance_fund;

Answer (score 0):

You have to use db functions inside the while loop and sleep connections.

```
    while($fund > 100)
    {

$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("select Member.sales_hold_fund,Member.referrer_member_id from Member where member_id=?");
    $stmt->execute(array($member_id));
    $memberC = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $fund = $memberC['sales_hold_fund'];

    ob_start();
    sleep(1);
................
............
}
```